# How do I prevent Windows 10's File History Service from gobbling up all my networking bandwidth?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, backup, file-history

I set up file history service to sync certain files to my local NAS which works great. The two are connected using a suboptimal "DLAN"/Powerline connection which reaches about 90 Megabits per second. The source PC uses the same Powerline to connect to a router and thus to the internet (16 Megabit down/2 Megabit up). The problem is that when File History Service is transferring data, I have almost no bandwidth left for even just surfing the web. All I can do is switch off my NAS to postpone the backup process, but that defeats its purpose. Is there a way to change the priority of the service or limit its available bandwidth? My NAS is running Ubuntu. Is there a way I can throttle incoming traffic from the local network on that end?